# AWS CodeCommit - What to use for updatePullRequestApprovalState param revisionId

Tags: aws-codecommit, aws-sdk-js

In the documentation for AWS SDK for JS and on the service reference pages for CodeCommit, the command `updatePullRequestApprovalState` requires the parameter `revisionId`, which is described as "The system-generated ID of the revision."

At first, I took this to be the `sourceCommit` from the pull request.

However, I get an error of:

```
{
    "errorType": "InvalidRevisionIdException",
    "errorMessage": "A revision ID is required, but the value is not valid. Revision IDs are 64 characters in length. To retrieve a valid revision ID, use GetPullRequest.",
    "code": "InvalidRevisionIdException",
    "message": "A revision ID is required, but the value is not valid. Revision IDs are 64 characters in length. To retrieve a valid revision ID, use GetPullRequest.",
    "time": "2019-12-15T18:15:07.927Z",
    "requestId": "229083c9-55b7-4775-af13-c2ebfbee8703",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 66.89618399186179,
    "stack": [
        "InvalidRevisionIdException: A revision ID is required, but the value is not valid. Revision IDs are 64 characters in length. To retrieve a valid revision ID, use GetPullRequest.",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

This indicates to use `GetPullRequest`, but the response of that contains no 64 character strings, nor a clear `revisionId`.

```
{
    "pullRequest": {
        "authorArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:myuser",
        "title": "pr#1",
        "pullRequestTargets": [
            {
                "repositoryName": "example-prb-impl",
                "mergeBase": "24863fed13a26c6a4c32ee8a707a9e8d78ee00a0",
                "destinationCommit": "24863fed13a26c6a4c32ee8a707a9e8d78ee00a0",
                "sourceReference": "refs/heads/test-branch",
                "sourceCommit": "c2d4911671a8bb78ab8882610ef014030edc0b9d",
                "destinationReference": "refs/heads/master",
                "mergeMetadata": {
                    "isMerged": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "lastActivityDate": 1576433707.07,
        "pullRequestId": "62",
        "clientRequestToken": "3b5f7c0b-1069-4453-b04d-96ca4a33b64a",
        "pullRequestStatus": "OPEN",
        "creationDate": 1576430500.539
    }
}
```

I also tried the `destinationCommit` and `mergeBase` values, but it was the same error.

What value should I be using here?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to upgrade the AWS CLI. After doing so, the response from getPullRequest contained more information, including `revisionId`.